# angular-ui/ui-sortable : Draggable item shifts to left

Tags: angularjs, css, angular-ui-sortable

Draggable item shifts to left with position:fixed parent container when clicked to drag.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$scope.sortableOptions = {
    helper: 'clone'
};
```

This code worked for me. Probably a jQuery issue.

Answer (score 0):

As you don't provide code i just can guess - try to set the appendTo option to e.g. the body element

see here: http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-appendTo

Example:

```
$scope.sortableOptions = {
    update: function(e, ui) { ... },
    axis: 'x',
    appendTo: document.body
  };
```